# where is the best place to save editable html pages to view on webview on android project (NOT IN ASSETS)?

Tags: android, storage, internal

i want to save HTML pages on my android projects. since assets folder is read only, 
i can not save them there, because i can not edit them if someday i need to, so where is the best place to save it?

Comment: You can place them in a web server and download to your cache folder or sd card

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your files inside the asset folder and copy them to the SD card the first time the application is started.
In this way you'll be able to edit those files if needed.

Helpful links:

- [How to copy files from assets to SD card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-in-assets-to-sdcard)
- [Intercept the first time the app is started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260972/function-which-implemented-once-in-android-app/16261019#16261019)